# Bug on Stack Exchange Mobile saving drafts

Tags: bug, tags, ios-app

So I was asking a question on meta Arqade and when I saved my draft to go look at some questions and go back to my saved draft it merges all my tags together…

It turned [image]

Into

[image]

Don't ask for the original question because I didn't post it.

This also happens on every stack exchange site.

Also, submitting the question with the weird tags brings up this...
[image]

If I try to submit it even if the required tags are met it says I need 500+ rep to create a new tag.

(App info)

> - App Version: 1.5.0.3
> - Device: iPhone 6
> - OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)